# is.character() does not correctly identify a data frame

Tags: r, character

Has the behavior of `is.character()` changed in R 4.x ?
Here I read a simple tab-delimited text file into a data frame, and then confirm all columns are correctly marked as character data:

```
> raw <- read.table( creditDataPath, header = TRUE, colClasses="character", sep = "\t")
> str(raw)
'data.frame':   407 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ NAME          : chr  "Hope Gorman" "Sarah Coriano" "Ernest Farmer" "John Coleman" ...
 $ ADDRESS       : chr  "179 Del Mar Blvd." "640 Prospect Lane" "474 Green Street" "452 Green Street" ...
 $ ZIP           : chr  "99975" "99904" "99900" "99924" ...
 $ SSN           : chr  "470-17-7670" "355-91-5677" "129-21-0468" "121-57-2753" ...
 $ SEX           : chr  "F" "F" "M" "M" ...
 $ MARITALSTATUS : chr  "M" "M" "M" "M" ...
 $ CHILDREN      : chr  "2" "1" "0" "0" ...
 $ OCCUPATION    : chr  "Professional" "Unknown" "Unknown" "Unknown" ...
 $ HOMEOWNERSHIP : chr  "O" "O" "O" "O" ...
 $ INCOME        : chr  "3212" "3145" "3165" "3248" ...
 $ EXPENSES      : chr  "1124" "1100" "1266" "974" ...
 $ CHECKING      : chr  "N" "N" "N" "N" ...
 $ SAVINGS       : chr  "Y" "Y" "Y" "Y" ...
 $ MSTRCARD      : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ VISA          : chr  "5" "5" "5" "5" ...
 $ AMEX          : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ MERCHANT      : chr  "9" "9" "9" "9" ...
 $ PAYMENTHISTORY: chr  "2" "0" "2" "3" ...
```

However, `is.character(raw)` for the data frame and `is.character(raw[3,1:17])` for a portion of a row in the data frame both return FALSE:

```
> is.character(raw)
[1] FALSE
> is.character(raw[3,1:17])
[1] FALSE
>
```

With R version **3.5.2** (the original development environment was 64-bit R 3.5.2 on 64-bit Win 7), simply reading the file into a data frame (***WITHOUT*** needing to add `colClasses = "character"` simply worked. The use case is that basically an R wrapper uses **`is.character()`** to determine whether a row in the data frame contains all string values (in effect: **`is.character(raw[n,1:17])`**); that then determines which version of a C function in a legacy DLL to call - one that expects either ALL strings, or one that expects ALL doubles).

I have been away from R since 2019, so today on a computer running Win10 Pro I installed 64-bit R 4.2.1, loaded the original workspace, and expected everything to work. And, if I manually craft a record (vector) that explicitly has every value in double quotes (e.g., "Hope Gorman", ""99975", etc.) everything does work - the R wrapper calls the correct C function.

The problem is, loading the data frame from the simple flat ASCII text file and then accessing it row by row does not work, even though after loading R seems to think the data consists of values that are quoted strings. The error is the dreaded **NAs introduced by coercion** error - in the wrapper R appears to NOT recognize the character strings.

What am I missing? Is this a bug in 4.x ?

**EDIT:**
Here are the first 4 lines of the file (first line contains column labels; 18 total **tab delimited** fields - some of the string fields contain spaces, e.g. `Hope Gorman` is the value for the first **Name** field/column). This is a toy (**ENTIRELY FAKED**) data file for consumer credit analysis.

```
NAME    ADDRESS ZIP SSN SEX MARITALSTATUS   CHILDREN    OCCUPATION  HOMEOWNERSHIP   INCOME  EXPENSES    CHECKING    SAVINGS MSTRCARD    VISA    AMEX    MERCHANT    PAYMENTHISTORY
Hope Gorman 179 Del Mar Blvd.   99975   470-17-7670 F   M   2   Professional    O   3212    1124    N   Y   1   5   0   9   2
Sarah Coriano   640 Prospect Lane   99904   355-91-5677 F   M   1   Unknown O   3145    1100    N   Y   1   5   0   9   0
Ernest Farmer   474 Green Street    99900   129-21-0468 M   M   0   Unknown O   3165    1266    N   Y   1   5   0   9   2
```

Also FWIW, I have checked everything on the original development machine (same file, same R workspace but R 3.5.2 running on Win7), and the R wrapper calls the correct C code as expected.

This leads me to think there is something different in R 4.2 running on Win 10 - I have noted that R now apparently uses UTF-8 characters, but since the file consists solely of US-ASCII characters and no BOM, I am hard-pressed to think character handling on Win10 is the problem, but the fact remains the original code/ R Workspace doesn't work.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: I don't understand how `is.character` on a `data.frame` would ever return `TRUE`, why should it? The premise of a `data.frame` is that it can contain different classes for each column; if you want to know if all columns are character, then perhaps `all(sapply(raw, is.character))`?

Comment: The class of "raw" is `data.frame` not  `character`, thus `is.character(raw)` returns false. The class of "raw[3,1:17]" is also `data.frame` (you're testing row 3, columns 3 to 17), thus "is.character(raw[3,1:17])" also return false.

Comment: Since your question mostly involves how R reads a CSV file, please supply your original CSV or an excerpt thereof.

Comment: If everything is `character`, and you want a row (or a piece of a row) to be treated as a character vector, then you want a `matrix` not a `data.frame`.

Comment: The only change I can think of is that in R 4.0.0 the default for reading it data was changed to `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. In R 3.5.2, if you omitted `colClasses = "character"` (as you say) and hadn't overrided a global option default, then all of those columns would have been read in as class `factor`, not `character`. Which makes it all the more confusing that you say in R 3.5.2 rows were treated as character vectors. I'd suggest posting some of the actual code - what line of code throws *"the dreaded NAs introduced by conversion error"*?

Comment: And how sure are you that the R 3.5.2 version didn't convert your data to a `matrix`, either explicitly with `as.matrix` or implicitly by using a function like `apply` that coerces its input to `matrix`?

Comment: The example CSV data you've copied can't be used. StackOverflow replaced all the tabs with spaces. Please upload a file somewhere.

Comment: @Casper V. Your edits are valid, though not being an R guru I was referring colloquially to a simple organization of data in rows and columns (from a function named read.table...). The "answer" I just posted has more detail.

Answer (score 2):

First, thanks to all the R Gurus who responded.

Second, and somewhat embarrassing, after re-learning how to use debugging tools in R, I discovered that the reason the code "ran" on **R 3.5.2** was that there was a bug in the legacy C DLL.

When I looked at the problematic R code statically, it appeared that the only way the R function could possibly call the correct DLL function was if **`is.character(data)`** returned true.

However, when I stepped through the code in the debugger (in the original Win7/R 3.5.2 environment), I found that **`is.character(data)`** was actually returning false - as everyone here expected (and Casper V. further demonstrated), ***BUT*** the C function in the Win7 DLL was still treating **`data`** as an array of character strings (which it should not have done, given the logic path in the R function).

I then discovered that the legacy DLL used on Win 10, which I thought was the same as that used in the Win 7 environment, was actually a later version, in which the bug was fixed (which of course caused the R error I was seeing in Win 10).

In the end, checking the data type in R as suggested by r2evans ultimately solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of `is.character()` that you describe doesn't seem to have changed. What you describe as the behavior for version 3.5.2 doesn't seem to be correct, as can be seen in my attempt to replicate it below.

As mentioned by @guasi, the class of your data frame *`raw`* is just `data.frame`. The class of a **column**, eg *`raw$NAME`*, can be `character`.

It is possible that you had/have a custom handler for `is.character()` to handle data frames on the 3.5.2 setup, and you didn't copy it to the new version:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/character

> `as.character` and `is.character` are generic: you can write methods to handle specific classes of objects, see `InternalMethods`

You mention that the same code on the old 3.5.2 install, still calls the correct C code. Have you checked yourself what the output of `is.character(raw)` is on that machine?

###### Reproduction attempt

I have installed R 3.5.2 64 bit on Win 7, and couldn't reproduce what you remember from the past:

File: [test.csv](https://pastebin.com/raw/knWnYKkA), created from example data, but tab delimited:

> Here are the first 4 lines of the file (first line contains column labels; 18 total tab delimited fields - some of the string fields contain spaces, e.g. Hope Gorman is the value for the first Name field/column).

Environment:

> the original development environment was 64-bit R 3.5.2 on 64-bit Win 7

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.2
```

Command:

> simply reading the file into a table (WITHOUT needing to add colClasses = "character" simply worked.

```r
> raw <- read.table('C:\\Users\\caspar\\Desktop\\test.csv', header=T, sep='\t')
> str(raw)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ NAME          : Factor w/ 3 levels "Ernest Farmer",..: 2 3 1
 $ ADDRESS       : Factor w/ 3 levels "179 Del Mar Blvd.",..: 1 3 2
 $ ZIP           : int  99975 99904 99900
 $ SSN           : Factor w/ 3 levels "129-21-0468",..: 3 2 1
 $ SEX           : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 2
 $ MARITALSTATUS : Factor w/ 1 level "M": 1 1 1
 $ CHILDREN      : int  2 1 0
 $ OCCUPATION    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Professional",..: 1 2 2
 $ HOMEOWNERSHIP : Factor w/ 1 level "O": 1 1 1
 $ INCOME        : int  3212 3145 3165
 $ EXPENSES      : int  1124 1100 1266
 $ CHECKING      : Factor w/ 1 level "N": 1 1 1
 $ SAVINGS       : Factor w/ 1 level "Y": 1 1 1
 $ MSTRCARD      : int  1 1 1
 $ VISA          : int  5 5 5
 $ AMEX          : int  0 0 0
 $ MERCHANT      : int  9 9 9
 $ PAYMENTHISTORY: int  2 0 2
```

```r
> is.character(raw)
[1] FALSE
```

```r
> is.character(raw[3,1:17])
[1] FALSE
```

*spacing between commands mine*

Here I assumed you mean the same command you used before, but without the colClasses parameter. `is.character()` is still `FALSE` **with** `colClasses = "character"`. It's more common to use `read.csv()`, but that yielded the same results as well.